# "floor" or "floors"?

Tags: grammar

> 1. On the landing between the 11th and 12th floors.
> 2. On the landing between the 11th and the 12th floor.

Is 'floors' correct in the first sentence and 'floor' correct in the second?

Is one more common than the other?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. In the second there's an implicit "floor":

> On the landing between the 11th [floor] and the 12th floor.

I think it would be hard to find out which is more common.

I would be inclined to use the first.

Comment: I'd definitely prefer the second (singular) and I feel like this is probably more common, but I completely agree both are acceptable.